# Problems upgrading to Apache Cayenne 4.0 BETA 1

Tags: java, apache-cayenne

I've just upgraded to Apache Cayenne 4.0 BETA 1 and I'mm getting these errors:
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header

It looks like they are spewed out by calling "org.apache.cayenne.Cayenne.objectForPK" and "org.apache.cayenne.CayenneDataObject.readProperty".

Here is the log:

```
INFO: *** error.
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303137
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.types.SerializableTypeFactory$SerializableType.toJavaObject(SerializableTypeFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.types.SerializableTypeFactory$SerializableType.toJavaObject(SerializableTypeFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.types.ExtendedTypeDecorator.materializeObject(ExtendedTypeDecorator.java:53)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.reader.FullRowReader.readRow(FullRowReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.reader.FullRowReader.readRow(FullRowReader.java:32)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.JDBCResultIterator.nextRow(JDBCResultIterator.java:104)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.JDBCResultIterator.allRows(JDBCResultIterator.java:80)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.SelectAction.performAction(SelectAction.java:138)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataNodeQueryAction.runQuery(DataNodeQueryAction.java:97)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataNode.performQueries(DataNode.java:293)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.runQuery(DataDomainQueryAction.java:471)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.access$000(DataDomainQueryAction.java:72)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction$2.perform(DataDomainQueryAction.java:446)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:87)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInLocalTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:40)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.runQueryInTransaction(DataDomainQueryAction.java:443)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.interceptOIDQuery(DataDomainQueryAction.java:172)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.execute(DataDomainQueryAction.java:117)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.onQueryNoFilters(DataDomain.java:564)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain$DataDomainQueryFilterChain.onQuery(DataDomain.java:748)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.TransactionFilter.onQuery(TransactionFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain$DataDomainQueryFilterChain.onQuery(DataDomain.java:748)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.onQuery(DataDomain.java:556)
    at org.apache.cayenne.util.ObjectContextQueryAction.runQuery(ObjectContextQueryAction.java:382)
    at org.apache.cayenne.util.ObjectContextQueryAction.executePostCache(ObjectContextQueryAction.java:107)
    at org.apache.cayenne.util.ObjectContextQueryAction.execute(ObjectContextQueryAction.java:94)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.onQuery(DataContext.java:965)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.performQuery(DataContext.java:954)
    at org.apache.cayenne.BaseContext.prepareForAccess(BaseContext.java:362)
    at org.apache.cayenne.CayenneDataObject.readProperty(CayenneDataObject.java:174)
    at com.starstv.databases.postgresql.accountsdb.cayennemodels.auto._Fan.getBecameInfluencerDateTime(_Fan.java:59)
    at com.starstv.databases.postgresql.accountsdb.dataservices.CelebrityServices.getInfluencersAsRPrettyGirlCelebrities(CelebrityServices.java:96)
    at com.starstv.actions.celebrity.CelebrityActions.getCelebrityInfluencersCount(CelebrityActions.java:100)
    at com.starstv.actions.celebrity.CelebrityActions.addCelebrity(CelebrityActions.java:108)
    at com.starstv.actions.fan.cache.CelebritiesCache.retrieveAllCelebrities(CelebritiesCache.java:63)
    at com.starstv.actions.fan.cache.CelebritiesCache.fetchAllCelebritiesJSONString(CelebritiesCache.java:69)
    at com.starstv.actions.fan.cache.CelebritiesCache.getAllCelebritiesJSONString(CelebritiesCache.java:80)
    at com.starstv.actions.celebrity.CelebrityActions.getAllCelebritiesNamesJSONString(CelebrityActions.java:36)
    at com.starstv.serverapps.fans.entrypoints.standard.CelebrityConnections.getAllCelebrities(CelebrityConnections.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jun 21, 2017 6:55:37 PM org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel handleException
WARNING: /celebrity/all/en
javax.servlet.ServletException: org.apache.cayenne.CayenneRuntimeException: [v.4.0.B1 Jun 02 2017 15:48:55] Query exception.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:308)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1621)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1593)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1562)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.cayenne.CayenneRuntimeException: [v.4.0.B1 Jun 02 2017 15:48:55] Query exception.
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.nextQueryException(DataDomainQueryAction.java:614)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataNode.performQueries(DataNode.java:299)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.runQuery(DataDomainQueryAction.java:471)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.access$000(DataDomainQueryAction.java:72)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction$2.perform(DataDomainQueryAction.java:446)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:87)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInLocalTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:59)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.DefaultTransactionManager.performInTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:40)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.runQueryInTransaction(DataDomainQueryAction.java:443)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.interceptOIDQuery(DataDomainQueryAction.java:172)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomainQueryAction.execute(DataDomainQueryAction.java:117)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.onQueryNoFilters(DataDomain.java:564)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain$DataDomainQueryFilterChain.onQuery(DataDomain.java:748)
    at org.apache.cayenne.tx.TransactionFilter.onQuery(TransactionFilter.java:49)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain$DataDomainQueryFilterChain.onQuery(DataDomain.java:748)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataDomain.onQuery(DataDomain.java:556)
    at org.apache.cayenne.util.ObjectContextQueryAction.runQuery(ObjectContextQueryAction.java:382)
    at org.apache.cayenne.util.ObjectContextQueryAction.executePostCache(ObjectContextQueryAction.java:107)
    at org.apache.cayenne.util.ObjectContextQueryAction.execute(ObjectContextQueryAction.java:94)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.onQuery(DataContext.java:965)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataContext.performQuery(DataContext.java:954)
    at org.apache.cayenne.BaseContext.prepareForAccess(BaseContext.java:362)
    at org.apache.cayenne.CayenneDataObject.readProperty(CayenneDataObject.java:174)
    at com.starstv.databases.postgresql.accountsdb.cayennemodels.auto._Fan.getBecameInfluencerDateTime(_Fan.java:59)
    at com.starstv.databases.postgresql.accountsdb.dataservices.CelebrityServices.getInfluencersAsRPrettyGirlCelebrities(CelebrityServices.java:96)
    at com.starstv.actions.celebrity.CelebrityActions.getCelebrityInfluencersCount(CelebrityActions.java:100)
    at com.starstv.actions.celebrity.CelebrityActions.addCelebrity(CelebrityActions.java:108)
    at com.starstv.actions.fan.cache.CelebritiesCache.retrieveAllCelebrities(CelebritiesCache.java:63)
    at com.starstv.actions.fan.cache.CelebritiesCache.fetchAllCelebritiesJSONString(CelebritiesCache.java:69)
    at com.starstv.actions.fan.cache.CelebritiesCache.getAllCelebritiesJSONString(CelebritiesCache.java:80)
    at com.starstv.actions.celebrity.CelebrityActions.getAllCelebritiesNamesJSONString(CelebrityActions.java:36)
    at com.starstv.serverapps.fans.entrypoints.standard.CelebrityConnections.getAllCelebrities(CelebrityConnections.java:22)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 32303137
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:857)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.types.SerializableTypeFactory$SerializableType.toJavaObject(SerializableTypeFactory.java:106)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.types.SerializableTypeFactory$SerializableType.toJavaObject(SerializableTypeFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.types.ExtendedTypeDecorator.materializeObject(ExtendedTypeDecorator.java:53)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.reader.FullRowReader.readRow(FullRowReader.java:52)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.reader.FullRowReader.readRow(FullRowReader.java:32)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.JDBCResultIterator.nextRow(JDBCResultIterator.java:104)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.JDBCResultIterator.allRows(JDBCResultIterator.java:80)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.jdbc.SelectAction.performAction(SelectAction.java:138)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataNodeQueryAction.runQuery(DataNodeQueryAction.java:97)
    at org.apache.cayenne.access.DataNode.performQueries(DataNode.java:293)
    ... 84 more
```

As for my setup, I'm including only these in my project:

```
third-party
cayenne-di-4.0.B1.jar
cayenne-server-4.0.B1.jar
(that's it).
```

It was working perfect fine in the Apache Cayenne 4 Milestone 5 release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved after adding "cayenne-java8-4.0.B1.jar".

Thanks for reading my question/answer! Cheers! :-)